# how to update all package version number in package.json when use `npm update`？

Tags: json, node.js, npm, nodes

when i use `npm update` , i can update all package , but package version number in package.json not change , in the package.json , have `devDependencies` and `dependencies` , like this :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lodash": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

how to use one line command update all package and all package numbner in `devDependencies` and `dependencies` will update too.

Comment: in package.json you can update each version to its latest version. For eg-> "jquery" : "*", thus jquery will be updated to its latest version.

Comment: @RiyaSaxena but when my project have package , i want to update package , just use `npm install` ,  don't need uninstall old package ?

Answer (score 6):

From [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update):

> When you want to update a package and save the new version as the
>   minimum required dependency in package.json, you can use:

```
npm update -S
```

or

```
npm update --save
```

Also As with all commands that install packages, the **--dev** flag will cause devDependencies to be processed as well. so your desired command is:

```
npm update --dev --save
```

**Note** that npm will only write an updated version to *package.json* if it installs a new package.

Answer (score 6):

One easy step:

> $ npm i -g npm-check-updates && ncu -a && npm i

That is all. All of the package versions in package.json will be the latest.

Answer (score 0):

By typing these commands in terminal you can update to latest dependencies in package.json

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
```

and go to your angular project with package.json and run:

```
ncu -u -a
```

it will update all of your dependencies to the latest.

Comment: in 2022, there is no ncu when npm-check-updates is installed